# Cannot see Server Tab tab in Eclipse (2019-06 on Mac) to add Tomcat Server

Tags: eclipse

Hope someone can help me. 
I have two issues.

1. I have installed the Web Development Tools (Install new Software) but there was no message that a restart of Eclipse was needed and after restart of Eclipse the "dynamic web project" was still not there.
2. I also tried to configure Apache Tomcat in Eclipse but I don't have the Server Tab (Maybe because also the "dynamic web project" is not there?!

I use Mac and have:

- Eclipse 2019-06
- Apache Tomcat 9.0.24
- jdk-12.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through a similar process, also on Eclipse 2019 IDE.

1. You must go to the Eclipse Marketplace in the Help dropdown.
2. Search for Server
3. Scroll down until you find Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, JOnAS, J2EE) Luna and click Install.

I then found the selection list only went up too Tomcat 8.0, which means you cannot configure for 8.5 or 9. After a bit of struggling I discovered i needed an Eclipse Software Update:

1. Select Check for Updates from the Help dropdown.
2. I discovered JST Server Adapters that needed updating. As soon as those were downloaded and installed i could see Tomcat 8.5 and Tomcat 9.0

Answer (score 1):

Add Servers Tab :

```
Window> Show View > Servers
```

And you can use :

```
Help > Search > Creating a server
```

To find some help.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [WTP FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F):

> ...complete support for "dynamic" web projects requires the full Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools Feature.

Beyond that, you will absolutely need the *JST Server Adapter Extensions* feature to support Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you.

So you mean this two right? 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-jst-server-adapters-apache-tomcat-jonas-j2ee

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0


Sorry i'm very very new :)

Comment: No, despite the last modified date and supported versions of the entry being recent, it's still pointing to old code. Ideally https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-ee-developer-tools-0 .

Comment: Hi, I have checked it together with a work collegue and I had to install "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers" https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-09/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers 
After that I have the option for "dynamic web project" and the "server" tab next to the console.

Thank you for your help. :)